# Scrollable Pagination Client-servers

Tags: java, swing, pagination, client-server

I have a client screen display a big list data in a JTable. The client is Swing application. It requests the data from a remote server. The list data need to be displayed in scrollable pagination mode. That means the rows should be requested only when user scroll the table (like the way Oracle Developer displays the queried data).
So is the any good practice to follow? My 2 main concerning aspects are data requesting method (e.g. slice query, id caching...) and GUI handling.

Answer (score 1):

[SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is ideal for this, as it allows the query to continue in the background while the GUI is continually updated. Because `JTable` uses the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render cells, performance—even for thousands of rows—is usually acceptable. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725).

Addendum: If you find that you want to enhance pagination, consider using `RowFilter`, as suggested [here](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/03/jtable-pagination-example-using.html), or simple controls, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481138/how-to-make-pagination-in-swing-java/1481468#1481468).

Comment: @mKorbel: I always welcome your insights. I hadn't looked at `ChristmasTree` in a while; very apropos.

Comment: @mKorbel and the xmas tree example it related to the OPs problem in that ... ? the xmas is an exercise  to increase the _rendering_ performance (not overly successful, as even the author Scott admitted:  many hacks, little gain, mainly because there isn't much to improve to start with ;)

Comment: @kleopatra painting in visible ViewPort, and if changed, then invoke action ..., or I'm wrong? where...

Comment: @mKorbel interpreting your sentence as a loose description of the "pagination" requirement - again (stubborn me ;-) and that is related to the xmas tree article because ...?

Comment: one Swing/Java guru who not survived owners changes for sun and java.net .... (Jtable, Jtree, TreeTable and Nimbus)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on JTable. However, the other interesting issue is how to make scrolling as smooth as possible.

Comment: The best leverage, especially on dual-core machines, is to fetch rows in the background and let `JTable` & `JScrollPane` optimize the foreground.