# Java Pagination Framework/Lib

Tags: java, database, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying data from database in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357349/displaying-data-from-database-in-jtable)

I would like to implement pagination for a Swing client and would need on the fly pagination.  Basically in a scroll pane as the user scrolls up and down, based on the location of the slide, we would get a page of data from the database and display this data.  Mainly because the database can have thousand of records and loading all of them up front would kill the Swing client.

I could write my own but was wondering if there exists a framework or library already.  It could be client side or server side or both.  It would need some sort of cache or a few pages.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any framework to do so. I'm afraid you'd have to make your own implementation. And turning a list into a table with pagination controls will make the task much simpler.

Comment: A lot depends on the model; for `TableModel` see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6633508/230513).