# showing jprogress bar during database fetch operation

Tags: java, swing

I am querying the history table having millions of records using java swing. So it takes 20 mins to complete the job. Until that I need to display jProgressBar or something to show the user that query is still running. How to do that? Also how to find the max number to progress bar? Since it has million rows I cannot use total row count to do it. Please asvise. Also suggest anyother option other than jProgressbar also.

Comment: Are you sure it will take 20 minutes always?

Comment: use `JProgressBar#getValue()` to get the current value of progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fetching all the records at a time fetch the data in **chunks**.

Now increment the progress bar once a chuck of data is received in the proposition of the chuck size and total no of records.

Fetching all the data in single transaction is not a good way if no of records are in millions. Sometime it results into `OutOfMemoryError` and `Transaction TimedOut`.

> If possible then design your application to **show data in pagination** that is more efficient and **will not take 20 minutes** to make end user happy.

---

Please have a look at below link to get it done:

- [How to make pagination in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481138/how-to-make-pagination-in-swing-java)
- [Retrieve huge result set from DB in chunks](http://www.coderanch.com/t/303525/JDBC/databases/Retrieve-huge-result-set-DB).

Sample query for reading data in chunks just like pagination:

```
select * 
  from (select q.*, rownum rnum
       from ( [your query goes here] ) q
      where rownum <= chunk_number * chunk_size )
  where rnum >= ( chunk_number -1) * chunk_size + 1
```

Comment: How to get the values like that. I havent heard of that before.

Comment: how are you fetching the data from database?

Comment: Something like just using normal query. Select name, id from employee_his; then write each record to an array and pass it to another method to write that as excel.

Comment: I have shared a link in my post.

Comment: This is ok but still I am wonder how progress bar knows max value and shows correct progress..

Comment: First get the total no of records let's suppose it is 1000. and chunk (page) size is 100 then just increment the progress bar by 10% for each chunk.

Comment: or you can do in this way also set `JProgressBar jbar = new JProgressBar(0,1000);`  and call `jbar.setValue(100)` for each data arrival. here min=0 and max=1000.

Comment: I am afraid to get row count since even that takes 3 mins min.. So that would delay my operation that 3 mins more..

Comment: That's I suggest you to use pagination in your application as mentioned in my post as well to make your end user happy that will take less than 1 minutes I guess because there is no meaning of fetching all the records at a time.